# First li is off-center in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-lists

Having a little trouble with a UL in IE - the first item of the list is indented, and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I've tried list-style-position, but no effect. You can see a screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot]

Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks!

Here's the relevant code:

```
    <div id="leftcolumn">
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="rightcolumn">
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

#rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.   Please provide a code sample of what you're working with here...  thanks.

Comment: Thanks - sorry, accidentally hit post before I finished adding everything. It's been updated.

Comment: Based on the code you provided, seems to work okay.   Take a look [HERE](http://jsbin.com/ukuBeRa/1/edit).  It must be some other CSS causing the issue?

Comment: Found it - i had "display: inline" for all my ULs earlier in the CSS file, and when I removed it they all lined up in IE. Sorry, should have included that in my original post - I'm a bit new to this!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please refer the link below,

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html

Hope this helps